# Google map circle needed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, geometry

I am facing problem to add a circle around my cursor at google map. Please help.My map is working well.Just need to add a circle around it.Thanks in advanced. I use this gmap version. https://github.com/marioestrada/jQuery-gMap

```html
<script>
var mapMarkers = [{
    address: " Acworth, GA 30102, United States",
    html: "<strong> Acworth, GA 30102</strong><br> Acworth, GA 30102, United States",
    icon: {
     image: "img/pin.png",
     iconsize: [26, 46],
     iconanchor: [12, 46]
    },
    popup: true
   }];
            
            
           

   // Map Initial Location
   var initLatitude = 34.114268;
   var initLongitude = -84.6315723;

   // Map Extended Settings
   var mapSettings = {
    controls: {
     draggable: (($.browser.mobile) ? false : true),
     panControl: true,
     zoomControl: true,
     mapTypeControl: true,
     scaleControl: true,
     streetViewControl: true,
     overviewMapControl: true
    },
    scrollwheel: false,
    markers: mapMarkers,
    latitude: initLatitude,
    longitude: initLongitude,
    zoom: 10
                
                
   };
            
            


            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            var map = $("#googlemaps").gMap(mapSettings);

   // Map Center At
   var mapCenterAt = function(options, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#googlemaps").gMap("centerAt", options);
   }

  </script>
```

Comment: Please add more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    center: geolocation,
    radius: position.coords.accuracy
  });
```